How to join a Windows machine to a 365 tenant that has InTune without enrolling
We have a 365 tenant subscription, and have InTune enabled. We also have 30 user machines that are joined to the AAD and have Business Premium subscriptions. They joined before we enabled InTune, so I'm trying to get them enrolled in a way that is guaranteed successful.
I have had mixed results so far, following advice that I've got from various sites and forums. I now have 24 of the 30 machines enrolled, but many of these have been a slog to complete. The remaining ones are execs, and I want to have a cast-iron, can't fail method of enrolling them with a single file delivered to them to run.
Editing GPEdit seems to be the most successful way, but I don't want my users messing about with that. I'd rather give them a file to run that automates it.
Following about a month of research and playing, I've written a batch file that I think should replicate what GPEdit does, and I need to test it before I unleash it on the execs.
I have a test machine that can be wiped and rebuilt whenever needed. My problem is that whenever I join it to Entra, it auto-enrols into InTune. I've switched auto-enrol off in the InTune console and left it for 24 hours, but the machine enrols. I've tried disabling enrolment on the machine in the GPEdit settings, but get errors about enrolment.
One thought is to set up a Business Standard account, join with that, and then switch to a premium one. Is there any other way of ensuring that it doesn't enrol?

Generally, I would recommend to Enroll to Intune to have MDM for your devices. Your goal doesn't look like a good practice. I presume you have a reason for that.
You can disable automated enrollment by modifying MDM user scope here: https://portal.azure.com/#view/Microsoft_AAD_IAM/MdmConfiguration.ReactView/appName/Microsoft%20Intune/appId/0000000a-0000-0000-c000-000000000000
More information about automatic enrollment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/enrollment/windows-enroll
